# Is there an interactive calendar widget that allows me to switch between agenda view and calendar view?

Tags: calendar, app-widgets

I'm looking for an interactive calendar widget that allows me to switch between agenda view and calendar view.

The Go Calendar widget is really useful allowing you to scroll through the agenda and also select the calendar view which allows you to easily create an event for a given date.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a calendar widget that offers similar features and usability. 
I'd like to change my default launcher but don't wanna lose the useful widget. 
Anyone know an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

[Agenda Widget Plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roflharrison.agenda.plus) allows a user to do this easily.

As far as full scale calendar app replacements go, give the excellent [Jorte Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.johospace.jorte) a try - it too has loads of widgets and many customizable settings.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!
Agenda Widget Plus is quite good and the design is really nice but I still miss the usability of the Go Calendar widget.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Business Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mikado.bizcalpro&feature=search_result#?t=W10.). It also has a [Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=netgenius.bizcal&feature=search_result#?t=W10.) version.

The Agenda widget scrolls up and down my touch-scrolling (for lack of a better term), unlike under widgets where you need to click an up / down button to scroll (like ProDo). If you click on the Adgenda widget, you can launch its Calendar. The Agenda widget also has an add button for creating new events.